# Jupyter error sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have SSHed into 2 different computers connected by AFS and am running Jupyter notebooks off of both of them. However, when I try to save the first notebook, I get an error `Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb database disk image is malformed`. I [suspect](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9293) this is due to concurrent writes to `nbsignatures.db`, but I'm unsure. My full error message is below.

```
[W YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS ServerApp] 500 PUT /api/contents/Untitled.ipynb?########## (127.0.0.1): Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb database disk image is malformed
[W YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS ServerApp] wrote error: 'Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb database disk image is malformed'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 911, in save
        self.check_and_sign(nb, path)
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/contents/manager.py", line 713, in check_and_sign
        self.notary.sign(nb)
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 477, in sign
        self.store.store_signature(signature, self.algorithm)
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 214, in store_signature
        if not self.check_signature(digest, algorithm):
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 241, in check_signature
        r = self.db.execute(
    sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1786, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/contents/handlers.py", line 266, in put
        await self._save(model, path)
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/contents/handlers.py", line 191, in _save
        model = await ensure_async(self.contents_manager.save(model, path))
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/utils/__init__.py", line 189, in ensure_async
        result = await obj
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/contents/largefilemanager.py", line 133, in save
        return await super().save(model, path)
      File "/nobackup/username/env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 927, in save
        raise web.HTTPError(500, f"Unexpected error while saving file: {path} {e}") from e
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error (Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb database disk image is malformed)
[E YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS ServerApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8080",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8080/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (OS; CPU; rv:##.0) Gecko/######## Firefox/###.0"
    }
[E YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS ServerApp] 500 PUT /api/contents/Untitled.ipynb?########## (user_hash@127.0.0.1) ###.##ms referer=http://localhost:8080/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb
```

How do I solve this? If I'm not concerned about saving the Jupyter notebook and want to continue doing computations on the same notebook, would there be issues?